# C# Days of the week tryparse string conversions

Tags: c#, string, int, switch-statement, tryparse

So I am currently trying to finish this program that when you input a number correlating to the days of the week, it reflects the text connected to the numeric variable. (IE : Sunday - 1, Monday - 2, etc etc.)

I have found a functioning code that makes the program work, but it outputs incorrect information. No matter what number I put in, it always displays Sunday. And it doesn't stop me from inputting bad variables. Which I want it to. I'm frustrated at this point and I am very new to all of this. Can someone check over my code and tell me what I'm doing incorrectly? Thank you.

```
private void OkButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string day ="1";
    int number;

    if (int.TryParse(day, out number))
    {
        if (number >= 7 && number <= 1)
        {
            switch (day)
            {
                case "1":
                    dayOutputLabel.Text = "Sunday";
                    break;
                case "2":
                    dayOutputLabel.Text = "Monday";
                    break;
                case "3":
                    dayOutputLabel.Text = "Tuesday";
                    break;
                case "4":
                    dayOutputLabel.Text = "Wednesday";
                    break;
                case "5":
                    dayOutputLabel.Text = "Thursday";
                    break;
                case "6":
                    dayOutputLabel.Text = "Friday";
                    break;
                case "7":
                    dayOutputLabel.Text = "Saturday";
                    break;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid number input. Please use a number between 1 and 7.");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please put in a valid number.");
    }
}

private void ExitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Close();
}
```

Comment: how are you providing the input? here `day ="1"` hardcoded and `int.TryParse(day, out number)` makes `number = 1`. So it `dayOutputLabel.Text` will always be Sunday as `day ="1"`.

Comment: Yes, I did. Like I said, I am very very fairly new to all of this. Your solution was great. I was wondering if you could explain to me how the .trim(); works? I very much appreciate your help. I've been stuck on this for hours and hours.

Comment: Trim() is a method which simply removes white space around strings. So for example it converts "5", " 5", " 5 ", "   5   ",  "  5           " etc...to just "5" That way your user can be a little sloppy with their spacing and still get the conversion to work. If you feel this answered your question please consider marking it as the accepted answer. Feel free to ask any other questions and good luck!

Comment: .NET provides a ```System.DayOfWeek``` enumeration that might be of more use here rather than the switch statement approach.  Be advised though that the number values for the enumeration range from 0 for Sunday through 6 for Saturday.  If the user is entering values from 1-7 then you'll need to first parse to integer like you are already doing, then decrement the parsed value, and finally cast to DayOfWeek which will output the string value when you pass it to label.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you've hard coded day = "1" (i.e. Sunday).

Also this is a mistake:

```
 if (number >= 7 && number <= 1)
```

Surely you meant...

```
 if (number >= 1 && number <= 7)
```

I can't tell precisely what sort of project you're working on, but the following slight modification works in wpf and should be all you need to solve this:

```
private void OKButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {                      
            string day = myTextBox.Text.Trim();
            int number = 0;

            if (int.TryParse(day, out number))
            {
                if (number >= 1 && number <= 7)
                {
                    switch (day)
                    {
                        case "1":
                            dayOutputLabel.Content = "Sunday";
                            break;
                        case "2":
                            dayOutputLabel.Content = "Monday";
                            break;
                        case "3":
                            dayOutputLabel.Content = "Tuesday";
                            break;
                        case "4":
                            dayOutputLabel.Content = "Wednesday";
                            break;
                        case "5":
                            dayOutputLabel.Content = "Thursday";
                            break;
                        case "6":
                            dayOutputLabel.Content = "Friday";
                            break;
                        case "7":
                            dayOutputLabel.Content = "Saturday";
                            break;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Invalid number input. Please use a number between 1 and 7.");
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment above... here is a possible solution using the `System.DayOfWeek` enumeration:

```cs
private void OKButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // this TryParse makes use of pattern matching
    if(int.TryParse(myTextBox.Text.Trim(), out var input) && input >= 0 && input <= 6)
    {
        // this should automatically convert to the name of the day of week
        // if not, add .ToString() at the end
        dayOutputLabel.Content = (DayOfWeek)input;
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show(
            text: "Please use a number between 0 and 6",
            caption: "Invalid Input",
            buttons: MessageBoxButtons.OK,
            icon: MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
}
```

And here is an another option using `Enum.TryParse()` instead:

```cs
private void OKButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // this TryParse makes use of pattern matching
    if(Enum.TryParse(myTextBox.Text.Trim(), out DayOfWeek input) &&
       input >= DayOfWeek.Sunday && input <= DayOfWeek.Saturday)
    {
        // this should automatically convert to the name of the day of week
        // if not, add .ToString() at the end
        dayOutputLabel.Content = input;
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show(
            text: "Please use a number between 0 and 6",
            caption: "Invalid Input",
            buttons: MessageBoxButtons.OK,
            icon: MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
}
```